# git group development server setup

Tags: git

I want to deploy git for my organisation. I want users to have no access to the server and to make commits only to the repository.
However I want the repository to be a real file system that I can use with an apache virtual host.
What I have done is the following:

```
cd /home/vhosts
git init --shared {projectname}
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

I then want to run `git reset --hard` after every push back to the main repository.

Is this a good idea? Should I have a second repository that does a `git pull` instead of a `git reset --hard`... which is heavier? Can I set this up to be a `hook`??

Thanks.

Comment: Is this question really so bad no one even wants to critique it?

Comment: I'm not understanding the setup. Why is the repository on this server "pushing back" to the main repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the setup you describe with a few modifications. Joe Maller has an excellent write-up that I used as a base for my configuration. [A web-focused Git workflow](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/)

Comment: I have a team that *cannot* test locally as they write reports against massive data sets that run on customized proprietary software. Anyone that is just doing web-development really shouldn't be doing this sort of thing. It really isn't that hard to setup opensource software on a laptop on any operating system, or in a VM, or in a container, on a good IDE that can run and debug web code locally. If anyone is thinking of using this answer today they should really thing thrice and look to migrate to a server setup that they can actually mirror locally for local dev/debug.

Comment: Having said that it I did set it up and also had the `post-update` hook that syncs the Hub repo to the Prime repo do "git push github master" to sync all the changes up to GitHub so that there is a central backup of everything that is going on. That way if the dev server running the Hub repo dies all the history is up on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the way to set this up is to have a "bare" repository that is the top level master that everybody pushes and pulls from. The web server running Apache has its own separate repository (if you're short on hardware, they can be on the same machine). You would install a post-commit hook on the master repository that triggers a "git pull" on the one for Apache under `/home/vhosts`. (This hook is simplest on one machine, but you can do it across machines if you set it up that way.)

To create a bare repository:

```
mkdir -p /home/git/{projectname}.git
cd /home/git/{projectname}.git
git init --shared --bare
```

A bare repository has no working copy at all, just the contents of the `.git` structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Apache has to do with it.

Just setup a repo, a bare one as Greg says, and have that be your main repo. People then pull from that, and when they're ready they push to it. You probably want to deny non-fast-forward merges on the main repo, so that people always pull the latest code, merge with it, and then push.

The best way to give people access to the repo is using the git daemon and the `git://` protocol.

If you want a web interface then use gitweb, but that's just a convenience.

Also there is some good discussion of different workflows in [section 5.1 of the Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html), which might help clarify what the best workflow is for you.